# record webcam video and audio using fckeditor in php. Donot use Red,wowza or flash server as i do work in wamp server

Tags: php, webcam, record, fckeditor

I have been trying to use fckedittor to record webcam audio and video,but unable to use it in php(wamp server).I found fckeditor commands everywhere but unable to find complete php code because i donot know how to use fckeditor commands.Please help